# MYSQL REGEXP INET_NTOA IP ADDRESS SEARCHING

Tags: mysql, regex, ip-address

I'm having trouble understanding why I get the following results from a MySQL query of IP addresses.  I'm storing IP addresses as INTEGERS.

```
mysql> SELECT ip AS ip FROM ipaddress;
+-----------+
| ip        |
+-----------+
| 168456058 |
| 168456059 |
| 168456060 |
| 168456061 |
| 168456317 |
| 168456570 |
| 168489683 |
| 168489583 |
| 168489683 |
+-----------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is how the data looks when converting the INTEGERS to an IP address.

```
mysql> SELECT INET_NTOA(ip) AS ip FROM ipaddress;
+---------------+
| ip            |
+---------------+
| 10.10.111.122 |
| 10.10.111.123 |
| 10.10.111.124 |
| 10.10.111.125 |
| 10.10.112.125 |
| 10.10.113.122 |
| 10.10.242.211 |
| 10.10.242.111 |
| 10.10.242.211 |
+---------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I search for a particular subnet, such as 111, I get the results I expect:

```
mysql> SELECT INET_NTOA(ip) AS ip FROM ipaddress WHERE INET_NTOA(ip) REGEXP '[[:<:]]111[[:>:]]';
+---------------+
| ip            |
+---------------+
| 10.10.111.122 |
| 10.10.111.123 |
| 10.10.111.124 |
| 10.10.111.125 |
| 10.10.242.111 |
+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If I use a decimal in the query, I get no results.

```
mysql> SELECT INET_NTOA(ip) AS ip FROM ipaddress WHERE INET_NTOA(ip) REGEXP '[[:<:]]\.111[[:>:]]';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

The decimal in the query works if I change the search query to .11.  This time, though, I get all of the .111, **and the .211**.

```
mysql> SELECT INET_NTOA(ip) AS ip FROM ipaddress WHERE INET_NTOA(ip) REGEXP '[[:<:]]\.11[[:>:]]';
+---------------+
| ip            |
+---------------+
| 10.10.111.122 |
| 10.10.111.123 |
| 10.10.111.124 |
| 10.10.111.125 |
| 10.10.242.211 |
| 10.10.242.111 |
| 10.10.242.211 |
+---------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why would the .11 search work and .111 not work and, when I use .11 to search, I get the .211 results as well?

Comment: Separately from your actual question, I just want to remark that it is a curious choice to store IP addresses as integers. Are you very tight on space? Or are you doing some fancy math on them? If you store them as a (slightly larger) string, you'll never need to do the conversions going in and out of internet address format.

Comment: I'm not tight on space.  I've actually stored IP addresses as strings for a long time but when I recently discovered MySQL's INET_NTOA function that allowed me to store IP's as integers, I thought that was a better solution when it comes to sorting by IP address.  I agree with you that storing them as strings is an easier solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is self-contradictory.

You are bounding your pattern on word boundaries, and then including a non-word character in the string you're looking for. Since the '.' character isn't a word character, there will never be any strings that are delimited by word boundaries that include the '.'.

Put another way, since the '.' is itself a word boundary, you are looking for [word-boundary][word-boundary][word], which cannot occur.

Just take out the word boundaries in your REGEXP:

```
WHERE INET_NTOA(ip) REGEXP '\.111'
```

Comment: If you persist with storing IP addresses as integers, be sure to make them UNSIGNED integers, or you'll get truncation for addresses biller than '127. ...'

Answer (score 1):

the [[:>:]] is used for words and separates using alphanumeric characters or underscores. Dot is not alphanumeric. you are loking for a separated word in a string where the word is not separated (dot is part of the word).
just use `WHERE INET_NTOA(ip) like "%.111"`